# How user file upload progress in ASP.Net MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, file-upload, c#-4.0

I am playing around with Asp.net MVC2 and trying to write a page which allows a user to upload a file to a server and then inserts a record of the file into a DB.

So far I have got everything working but I am struggling to workout how to show the user progress of the file upload or to notify them that the file is being uploaded to the server.

Can someone help me and explain the best way of doing this?

Many thanks,

Morris

Comment: It's difficult, and requires client-side scripting (JavaScript or Flash, usually) but there are commercial and free components which do it, e.g., http://www.uploadify.com/ -- have you looked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use client-side upload controls that support progress. [Here's one](http://www.uploadify.com/demos/).

Comment: Note: Don't forget that a Flash component does NOT send (authentication) cookies when uploading files to your server.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to get back to you. Thanks for the ideas about trying these, Ill  investigate and let you how I get on with it